# UI Test target does not recognize Swift package from custom framework in xcworkspace

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, package

I am developing several projects in a single workspace (monorepo). The workspace contains a shared framework that contains code shared between the projects. Some of the code depends on external packages that I import using the Swift Package Manager. Everything is working except that the packages aren't recognized when I use the UI testing target. When I run the UI tests for one of the projects it complains that the packages cannot be found (in the framework). Another solution that suits my needs is also welcome. Anyway, I'm using Xcode 11.3. To reproduce:

1. Create a new workspace.
2. Add a new project A and a new framework B into the workspace.
3. Add any dependency (for example SDWebImage) to the framework.
4. Add a Swift-file to the framework that just does `import SDWebImage`.
5. Now add framework B as a dependency to project A.

If you build project A or unit test project A, there is no problem. However, when you run UI tests on project A it complains that it cannot find the module SDWebImage in the Swift-file you added in point 4 above. Any idea how to solve this?

Edit: When I use Cocoapods instead it gives me the same error. When I use use_frameworks! it doesn't give me the error, but it crashes with "SDWebImage: image not found".

Comment: I did manage to resolve this with Cocoapods but I'd like to move over to SPM.

Answer (score 18):

You have to manually add your B framework as a linked library in on your UI Tests target under Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

Comment: Great answer!  Worked for me after 2 hours of trying other stuff.  Thanks Alex

Comment: thx @D.Rothschild

Comment: that fixes the build for me, but on the flip side on Xcode 15 the UI tests are crashing on launch with tons of "Class XYZ is implemented in both" errors (where XYZ is a made up name for a class in the B framework - the log repeats for each existing class)